# Compare current date and time iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                         [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
NSDate* firstDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:resultString];
NSDate* secondDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"16:00"];
NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [secondDate timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate];

if (timeDifference < 0){
```

I'm trying to retrieve the current time and compare it with an input time. This is part of my code as of now (objective c for iOS), but NSTimeInterval causes a breakpoint. As an addition to this I would also like to incorporate the date into the comparison, so if it's after 5:00pm on Tuesday an event would occur. So if you have any ideas on how to incorporate that as well it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: John's answer below is the basic form for comparing the dates. (And note that there's no need to convert into a string and back again before comparing.) That line about "after 5pm on Tuesday" is a little sneaky and might warrant a separate question-- need to specify behaviors diff time zones, whether it's "any" Tuesday, etc

Answer (score 2):

To compare two dates:

```
if ([firstDate compare:secondDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"firstDate is later than secondDate");
    NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [firstDate timeIntervalSinceDate:secondDate];
} else if ([firstDate compare:secondDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"firstDate is earlier than secondDate");
    NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [secondDate timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate];
} else {
    NSLog(@"firstDate and secondDate are the same");
}
```

This should solve your problems.

Comment: What if I want it to be only for a certain day? Say if its 5:00 on Tuesday an event would occur, but Wed at 5:00 it wouldnt.

Comment: @DSmith: A "date" as embodied by an NSDate object like this represents a specific single point in real-world time in an absolute global sense. That point in time can be rendered as a date-and-time for a certain time zone, or compared to other specific points in time. It does *not* indicate a general "time-of-day" or any other general concept. If you wish to figure out how to represent what you're looking for you might want to ask that question more specifically for best help modeling it.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                         [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
NSDate* firstDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:resultString];
NSDate* secondDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"16:00"];
 NSComparisonResult result = [secondDate compare:firstDate];
        switch(result){
            case NSOrderedDescending:
                NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");
                break;
            case NSOrderedAscending:
                NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"dates are the same");
                break;
         }
```